# Unable to access request body using getBodyAsJson() in Vert.X 3.0.0

Tags: http, vert.x

I am using Vert.x  3.0.0-milestone5, to develop a sample web application. Everything is working fine as far as the routing is concerned, but I am not able to access request parameters using 
`routingContext.getBodyAsJson()` or
 `routingContext.getBody()` or 
`routingContext.getBodyAsString()`. 
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vertx/aa6pOs2FXWE) is the complete description.

Comment: Ok got it. we need to create BodyHandler using router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create()). Thanks to Tim Fox https://www.linkedin.com/in/timfox.

Comment: http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/

Answer (score 37):

If you want to use

```java
routingContext.getBody();
routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
```

You first need to add a body handler like below:

```java
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
```

Answer (score 0):

In new version of Vert.x these methods are Deprecated: [link](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#getBodyAsString--)

So, you need to use **body();.** Or add this tag before **@Deprecated**

```
@Deprecated
routingContext.getBody();
routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
```

***Reference:***
[Here](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#body--)